# Consolidating Similar Tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

An example that I want to give is that I see two similar tags that mean the same thing:

1. [graph-database](/questions/tagged/graph-database)
2. [graph-databases](/questions/tagged/graph-databases)

As you can see the only difference is the "s" at the end I am sure there are more examples like this.
There might be multiple approaches for solving this.

From the moderator/admin getting a monthly report on similar tags and making modifications manually or something more brilliant.

I am not sure if anyone has noticed this and if it is an issue for others but I just wanted to point it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably best to have one as a synonym of the other and then to manually retag the rest (there are only 6 in [graph-database](/questions/tagged/graph-database) and 29 in [graph-databases](/questions/tagged/graph-databases) currently).  I don't have enough rep to suggest the tag synonym, so maybe a moderator can take care of that.

Good catch, catching these early is always best to make it less painful.

**edit**:  [graph-database](/questions/tagged/graph-database) is empty now and I moved everything to [graph-databases](/questions/tagged/graph-databases)